# logging in TDD with Junit

Tags: java, logging, junit

Recently some one told me that we should not have logging in JUnit test cases or TDD in general. As I have started my self on TDD and it has helped me a lot, I see TDD as part of the code and I used log4j for my test methods. My reason: I was writing code in TDD test cases in JUnit so i should use logging for it as well.

What is the general prevalent opinion on this, i searched on this but couldn't find anything related to this on google. my sample test method will look something like this where destinationFileName is a class instance variable which is initialized in @BeforeTest method... Tell me if this logging is good or should not be added to test methods.

```
  @Test
    public void testProcessDestinationByStAX() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Testing processDestinationByStAX");
        DestinationProcessor destinationProcessor = new DestinationProcessor();
        int expResult = numOfDestinations;
        logger.info("parsing  " + destinationFileName);
        List<Destination> result = destinationProcessor.processDestinationByStAX(destinationFileName);
        logger.info("Successfully Parsed  : " + result.size() + " destinations ...");
        assertEquals(expResult, result.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IHMO, if logging is useful to determine what it going on it should be in the code not the tests. JUnit will log the test name (which should provide information about what is under test) and the code should have debug logging to help determine flow. Given these two things, I would normally suggest that logging in the tests cluttered and also clutters the log.

I also find that tests should be kept as simple as possible. This is because people don't like to maintain then. The more lines of code (including logging statements) in your tests, the more complex they become. People will spend time trying to figure out what you code does. They will not spend time trying to figure out what you test does. For this reason KISS is key to tests.

All that said, I think it would be hard for someone to suggest that there is anything inherently wrong with adding logging to your tests.

Another question might be, should you test logging? Should your unit test verify that expected logging takes place. I have not seen much discussion of this but IMHO, logging at the levels of WARNING or above should be verified.

On a slight side note, looking at your test it is not immediately obvious what is the method under test.  Consider formatting your test as follows:

```
 @Test
public void testProcessDestinationByStAX() throws Exception {
    // setup
    logger.info("Testing processDestinationByStAX");
    DestinationProcessor destinationProcessor = new DestinationProcessor();
    int expResult = numOfDestinations;
    logger.info("parsing  " + destinationFileName);

    // test
    List<Destination> result = destinationProcessor.processDestinationByStAX(destinationFileName);

    // verify
    logger.info("Successfully Parsed  : " + result.size() + " destinations ...");
    assertEquals(expResult, result.size());
}
```

This make your test clearer in that there should be exactly one invocation of the method under test and doing the formatting make it easy to find that invocation.

Comment: I like the formatting part yes it does give a lot of code visibility

Answer (score 0):

I think logging is useful in most case. For instance, a test time out and didn't throw exceptions. The log may help you find the problem. When we run a test case, you may see the log to see which process it is in and also we can check something that is hard to check with assert.

The opinion below is a little different. The key point of it would be sometimes the log information can be tracking and also the log in an automatic tool will be maintained for review or something.

---

In my opinion, most test cases don't need log4j to maintain the log. System.out.println() is enough for most scenario. **Assert message** is much more important.

But there are some special cases which log4j would be very useful.
For instance, 
[Where do I configure log4j in a JUnit test class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878348/where-do-i-configure-log4j-in-a-junit-test-class)

> I still need to run a test case by itself some times, in which case I
>   want log4j configured.

In this case, he need it run by itself sometimes and need to maintain a log for it.

Of course, if you have a teamcity to maintain every build log, you can use System.out.println as well. Because teamcity or other automatic tools help you maintain the log. If you don't use those tools and still want to run the test case many times, also need to know when a test case failed in which build with which check-in. Then the log4j would be useful.

In a word, I think we should avoid using log4j in a general Junit test case if we don't have some special requirement.

I think this is not related with TDD, or in a [TDD](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html), this is not the most important things.

Comment: You seem to be discussing whether log4j is the right logging mechanism, whereas the question asks: should logging happen at all.